# Missing data when ordering Pyspark Window

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my current dataset:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

df = spark.createDataFrame([("2","1",1),
                            ("3","2",2)],
                     schema = StructType([StructField("Data",  StringType()),
                                          StructField("Source",StringType()),
                                          StructField("Date",  IntegerType())]))


display(df.withColumn("Result",psf.collect_set("Data").over(Window.partitionBy("Source").orderBy("Date"))))
```

Output:

| Data | Source | Date | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | ["2"] |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | ["2","3"] |

Why am I missing value `3` in the first row of column `Result` when using collect_set function over Window that is `ordered` ?

I have tried to use `collect_list` as well, but I am getting same results.

My desired output is:

| Data | Source | Date | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | ["2","3"] |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | ["2","3"] |

where the order of values in `Result` is preserved - first one is where `Date = 1` and second one is `Date = 2`

Comment: see rowsBetween : https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.rowsBetween.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a Window with `unboundedPreceding` and `Window.unboundedFollowing`:

```
Window.partitionBy("Source").orderBy("Date") \
  .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
```

By default Spark uses `rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)` when you have an `orderBy`